# Assigning flag to the end of a collection of series

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I have a large number of series(in the form of `Rules`) and want to assign flag at the highest order of each of the rules. What I mean, is following. Take the list of two series with respect to $\epsilon$: one ends at $\epsilon^2$ and another at $\epsilon^3$

```
list = {a[x] -> 
   Subscript[C, -2]/ϵ^2 + Subscript[C, -1]/ϵ + 
    Subscript[C, 
    0] + ϵ Subscript[C, 1] + ϵ^2 Subscript[C, 2], 
  b[x] -> Subscript[D, -2]/ϵ^2 + Subscript[
    D, -1]/ϵ + Subscript[D, 
    0] + ϵ Subscript[D, 1] + ϵ^2 Subscript[D, 
     2] + ϵ^3 Subscript[D, 3]}
```

For the first list, I want to give a flag `\[Epsilon]^3*flag*a` where `a` is the name at left. Similarly the second series should be flagged as `\[Epsilon]^4*flag*b`. But I can not autodetect the order of $\epsilon$, hence what I could do

```
list[[1, #]] -> list[[#, 2]] + ϵ^3*flag*list[[#, 1]] & /@ {1,
   2}
```

which is true for lists with same order of highest $\epsilon$. How to generalize it?

Comment: Try: `list /. {HoldPattern[a : _[x] -> b___] :>    a -> b + \[Epsilon]^Exponent[b, \[Epsilon]] flag a}`

Comment: It seems that you have never accepted an answer. You can do so once per question asked by clicking the check mark next to the answer of your choice. It is customary to provide feedback once answer(s) are posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
list = {a[x] -> 
   Subscript[C, -2]/ϵ^2 + Subscript[C, -1]/ϵ + 
    Subscript[C, 
     0] + ϵ Subscript[C, 1] + ϵ^2 Subscript[C, 2], 
  b[x] -> Subscript[D, -2]/ϵ^2 + 
    Subscript[D, -1]/ϵ + 
    Subscript[D, 
     0] + ϵ Subscript[D, 1] + ϵ^2 Subscript[D, 
      2] + ϵ^3 Subscript[D, 3]}

f = Append[Values@#, 
    Head@Keys@# flag Power[ϵ, 
      1 + Cases[Values@#, Power[ϵ, a_] :> a, {2}] // Max]] &;

f /@ list
```

[image]